# How to return Value from Vue.extend?

Tags: vue.js

I have got the following code:

```
var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
  props : ['username','password'],
  template: `
    <div id="auth">
        <form class="form-inline pull-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="UserName">User name</label>
              <input type="username" v-model="username" class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="sendLoginInfo()">Войти</button>
        </form>
    </div>`,
    data: function()
    {
      return
      {
       // How to return username
      }
    }

});
```

I want to create a function that returns the username from an input field and send it to the server. How do I achieve this? Create new Vue instance like `Auth` and pass this data to it and in it pass them to server or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a method for the form being submitted that will send the values to the server.  In the template, you'd add

```
<form class="form-inline pull-right" v-on:submit.prevent="login">
```

When the form is submitted, it will automatically call `e.preventDefault()` so the page won't reload, then it will look for a function called `login`. So in your Vue object, add:

```
methods:{
    login: function(){
        //send form values to server
        // use ajax OR use this.$http if you are using the vue-resource extension
        this.$http.post('path/to/login', {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        }).then(function(response){
            //handle response
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use already existent in form `v-on:click="sendLoginInfo()"`?

Comment: Yep that's fine.  You don't need the `()` though, it will look for a function with that name.